# How to Automatically pressing enter while task scheduler is running

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

When running a program via the task scheduler (cmd), it is necessary to press enter every 5 minutes. How can I do that.
The reason I do this is because the program throws an error intermittently. Pressing the enter key is necessary to bypass this error. The program runs for about 3 hours.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you already try? Something like autoit `https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm` (doesn't need Windows to be active) or `https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm` might work. Best solutions would be to fix the applikation error. Google gives you alot solutions.